# PostgreSQL with named volume isn't starting the second time

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, bitnami

I'm using the `bitnami/postgresql:9.6` docker image to start postgresql DB. I want to persist data between restarts of containers and I used named volumes. Here is my docker file config:

```yaml
  postgresql:
    image: 'bitnami/postgresql:9.6'
    ports:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_MODE=<name>
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_USER=<name>
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD=<name>
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=<name>
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=<name>
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=<name>
      - POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="--encoding=utf8"
    volumes:
      - volume-postgresql:/bitnami/postgresql/data

    volumes:
      volume-postgresql:
```

but when I restart container I get following error:

```html
postgresql  | nami    INFO  Initializing postgresql
postgresql  | Error executing 'postInstallation': initdb: directory "/opt/bitnami/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
postgresql  | If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
postgresql  | the directory "/opt/bitnami/postgresql/data" or run initdb
postgresql  | with an argument other than "/opt/bitnami/postgresql/data".
```

Can you please help me to find what is the problem? Actually I expected that volumes are used for such purposes... Probably I make something wrong

Comment: As you said the volume mountintf is to maintan the persistancy. But this should not be the case of default behaviour of the container. Have you added any Scripts to execute the scripts when you run the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like I used wrong directory. Based on this site https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/postgresql/ I should use **/bitnami** instead of **/bitnami/postgresql/data**